# Cannot destructure ref property as it is undefined trying to use a multiple ref context

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-context, use-ref, react-ref

I want to make a ref context, using that context's refs in my sections and then consuming the context in my navbar to use intersectionObserver.

Trying to achieve this at first i created a context with every ref and then using the context in my about component.

The context looks like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from "react";

export const RefsContext = createContext();

export const RefsProvider = (props) => {
  const aboutRef = useRef();
  const shopRef = useRef();
  const customersRef = useRef();
  return (
    <RefsContext.Provider
      value={{
        aboutRef,
        shopRef,
        customersRef,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </RefsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RefsProvider;
```

And this is how i consume that context in my about.js:
First i import the context: `import { RefsContext } from "../../../context/refsContext";` then i use it: `const { aboutRef } = useContext(RefsContext);` and here i use that ref to referenciate a section: `<section className="about" id="about" ref={aboutRef}>`

I get this error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'aboutRef' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.` in about.js:10, this line: `const { aboutRef } = useContext(RefsContext);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to wrap whatever component is using this in `RefsProvider`. Does that fix this problem?

EDIT: To provide further context, if you use `useContext` inside a component that is not wrapped in the Provider for the context you are accessing, the value will be `undefined`. I suspect that is what is happening here.

In order to fix this, you need to wrap the component in `RefsProvider`

For example:

```
<RefsProvider>
  <YourComponentThatUsesRefsContext />
</RefsProvider>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31136700)

Comment: @slideshowp2 the answer I was suggesting was to wrap the component in `RefsProvider`. However by post was not very detailed or explicit. I've updated it to make it better. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Yeah this was it, totally forgot about it. No problem with the fact that you made it an answer instead of a comment.